# Integrating Spring Security with a JQuery Login Page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, authentication, spring-security

Here is a document about integrating Ext JS with Spring Security:

[Integrating Spring Security with Ext JS Login Page](http://loianegroner.com/2010/02/integrating-spring-security-with-extjs-login-page/)

Is there any simple working example that uses JQuery and makes an Ajax login page?(No need to use any more libraries)

**PS:** When I use that example many this are deprecated, I don't want to use deprecated ones.

Comment: the server logic is still the same. Probably this question doesn't need a `spring-security` tag. By the way, [thats](http://loianegroner.com/2010/02/integrating-spring-security-with-extjs-login-page/) the link you try to put in your question?

Comment: @bluefoot I have updated the link, thanks. I put spring-security tag because I want to simulate the same thing what it does at it's default login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just enough:

```
URL / form action: j_spring_security_check
Username input name: j_username
Password input name: j_password
```